# Trouble with lookup relationship parent query

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

I'm trying to construct a query that takes a specific `Contract` with a provided `Id`, and I want to fetch from this record, the related `Order`'s, and their `OrderItem`'s,

So If I understand correctly I would need to do as a first instance, where `sid` is the provided ID.

```
SELECT Id,
       Name,
       Account.Name, 
       (SELECT Id, Name FROM Order)
FROM Contract
WHERE ID = :sid
```

And the Error I get, is the following, but so far, I don't understand If I'm constructing the query in the wrong way, or what am I doing wrong in general with this, I want to avoid multiple SOQL, because of a POST-Query Manipulation I want to save EXEC-time, with doing only one query.

```
       (SELECT Id, Name FROM Order)
                             ^
ERROR at Row:4:Column:30
Didn't understand relationship 'Order' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Any Idea, how can I do this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right query

```
SELECT Id,
        Name,
        Account.Name,
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Orders) 
FROM Contract
```

Note the plural "s" after the word `Order`

Since you're querying for children, you have to pick the relationship name, not the object. For standard relationships, this is usually a plural of the object name (this will be likely different for custom relationships)

Comment: This is so weird, so, for the standar objects when ever I do children query like this I need to use the Plural for Standar Objects and the `__r` for custom?

Comment: Standard objects are a little different, since their names are hardcoded in the app. Custom relationhips afford you some control. You normally use `__r` when you go from child-to-parent. And use the plural when you go from parent-to-child (via subquery).